# Getting hierarchieal data using SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Following are my tables

```
PARTY
ID, PARTY_ID, PARENT_ID

PARTY_PARTY
BUYER_ID, SUPPLIER_ID
```

`PARTY` table holds records of both Buyer and Supplier. Buyer will have one or more child-buyers(referred by `PARENT_ID` column by child-buyer) and those child-buyers can have child-buyers in turn.

Each buyer can have one or more suppliers as well and this association tracked in `PARTY_PARTY` table, where `BUYER_ID` column holds buyer id and `SUPPLIER_ID` column holds his supplier id.

I am able to get all buyers and suppliers of given buyer like this

**Getting all hierarchical buyers for given buyer**

```
SELECT ID FROM party START WITH party_id = 'BUYERX' CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id;
```

**Getting all suppliers of above buyers**

```
SELECT ID
        FROM party
        WHERE ID IN (
                SELECT SUPPLIER_ID
                FROM party_party
                WHERE BUYER_ID IN (
                        SELECT ID
                        FROM party START WITH party_id = 'BUYERX' CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = parent_id
                        )
                )
```

But the problem here is - that resultant supplier can act as buyer for another supplier. In that case how can I get all buyers and suppliers, where buyers include both buyers and suppliers acting as buyers.

I don't want to use any views or procedures!

**Sample Data**

```
PARTY
ID, PARTY_ID, PARENT_ID
1, BX, NULL
2, BY, 1
3, BZ, 1
4, SA, NULL
5, SB, NULL
6, SC, NULL
7, SD, NULL
8, SE, NULL
9, SF, NULL

PARTY_PARTY
BUYER_ID, SUPPLIER_ID
1, 4
2, 5
3, 6
6, 7
6, 8
8, 9
```

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer to check if the output of my query for your sample data is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you would provide sample data. If I understood the relations between the buyers, suppliers and parents correctly, you can try this solution:

```
WITH
  party AS (
          SELECT 1 AS id, 'BUYERX' AS party_id, NULL AS parent_id FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 2 AS id, 'B02' AS party_id, 1 AS parent_id FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 3 AS id, 'B03' AS party_id, 1 AS parent_id FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 4 AS id, 'B04' AS party_id, 2 AS parent_id FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 5 AS id, 'B05' AS party_id, 3 AS parent_id FROM dual
  ),
  party_party AS (
          SELECT 2 AS buyer_id, 5 AS supplier_id FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 1 AS buyer_id, 4 AS supplier_id FROM dual
  )
SELECT
    id, LPAD('  ', (level - 1) * 2) || party_id AS party_id, parent_id, level
  FROM (
    SELECT id, party_id, parent_id
      FROM party
    UNION ALL
    SELECT supplier_id AS id, 'Supplier' AS party_id, buyer_id AS parent_id
      FROM party_party
  )
START WITH party_id = 'BUYERX'
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
;
```

Output:

```
   ID PARTY_ID       PARENT_ID   LEVEL
----- -------------- ---------   -----
    1 BUYERX                         1
    2   B02                  1       2
    4     B04                2       3
    5     Supplier           2       3
    3   B03                  1       2
    5     B05                3       3
    4   Supplier             1       2
```

**Edit** for your sample data, my query returns this output:

```
ID   PARTY_ID           PARENT_ID  LEVEL
---- ------------------ ---------  -----
 1   BX                                1
 2    BY                        1      2
 5      Supplier                2      3
 3    BZ                        1      2
 6      Supplier                3      3
 7        Supplier              6      4
 8        Supplier              6      4
 9          Supplier            8      5
 4    Supplier                  1      2
```

Comment: @Kruglej - added sample data

Comment: @Pokuri and could you please add expected result... have you even tried my solution? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way, without CONNECT BY:

```
  WITH   
  party AS (  
          SELECT 1 AS id, 'BUYERX' AS party_id NULL AS parent_id FROM dual  
    UNION SELECT 2 AS id, 'B02' AS party_id, 1 AS parent_id FROM dual  
    UNION SELECT 3 AS id, 'B03' AS party_id, 1 AS parent_id FROM dual  
    UNION SELECT 4 AS id, 'B04' AS party_id, 2 AS parent_id FROM dual  
    UNION SELECT 5 AS id, 'B05' AS party_id, 3 AS parent_id FROM dual  
  ),  
  party_party AS (  
          SELECT 2 AS buyer_id, 5 AS supplier_id FROM dual  
    UNION SELECT 1 AS buyer_id, 4 AS supplier_id FROM dual  
  ),  
  merged(id,party_id,parent_id)as(  
    SELECT id, party_id, parent_id  
      FROM party  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT supplier_id AS id, 'Supplier' AS party_id, buyer_id AS parent_id  
      FROM party_party),  
  grouped(par,node,clevel,client)as(  
  select parent_id,id,1,party_id from merged where parent_id is null union all  
  select c.parent_id,c.id,s.clevel+1,lpad(' ',4*s.clevel)||c.party_id  
  from merged c  
  join grouped s on s.node=c.parent_id)  
  select * from grouped order by par nulls first,clevel,node
```